# Update statement not working because subquery returns more than 1 value

Tags: t-sql

I try to update parts of an entire column (EquipmentEvents_ID_f) based on a condition that compares time stamps from different tables. If the time stamps are identical, an ID should be inserted from one table to the other. However, my subquery returns multiple values, which is logical. But how can I achieve to reduce the subquery… I am looking forward to your suggestions! Thanks

I cannot use the TOP 1 statement here

```
update [MES].[MAINT].[PrioTable_Test_PR]
set [EquipmentEvents_ID_f] = 
(
    select  a.ID
    from [MES_Archive].[OEE].[A_EquipmentEvents] as a
    where a.TimeStamp in 
    (
        select b.PrioTable_timestamp_equipmentBreakdown 
        from [MES].[MAINT].[PrioTable_Test_PR] as b 
        where a.TimeStamp = b.PrioTable_timestamp_equipmentBreakdown
    )
)
```

Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly clear to me what it is you're trying to do, but I think your code can be translated to an update with a join like this:

```
UPDATE t
SET [EquipmentEvents_ID_f] = a.ID
FROM [MES].[MAINT].[PrioTable_Test_PR] As t
JOIN [MES_Archive].[OEE].[A_EquipmentEvents] as a
    ON a.TimeStamp = PrioTable_timestamp_equipmentBreakdown
```

This way, you set the `EquipmentEvents_ID_f` to the `ID` value of the other table where the timestamp of both records is the same.
Please note, however, that uf you have multiple records in `[MES_Archive].[OEE].[A_EquipmentEvents]` that correspond to the same Timestamp, you might get unexpected results - since the `id` value that will be selected is going to be arbitrary.